# Firebase storage token error in native android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building a native android app using firebase and using storage storage in it. Here are my rules setup in storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read;
       allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have enabled enforce in too in storage.

Added SHA1 and SHA256 debud and production keys in frebase storage console.

I have tried to read storage using `listAll` but getting this error:

> Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

I need to get the image url's and display in my `imageview` in `recyclerview`.

I tried to signin anonymolly too but getting this eror:

> StorageException has occurred.
> > User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
>
> Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
> 2024-01-21 12:16:40.921  7747-7801  StorageException        com.madevina.laxmitelugutech         E  {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
> java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}